# How can I run this Curl script from Win10 batch file or command line?

Tags: curl

New to Curl and I need help getting started....

I need to run the following Curl script from a Win10 batch file and I cannot figure how to modify it to overcome Windows' not allowing cr/lf in the command shell.

Can someone please let me know the changes I need to make?

```
curl -X POST 'https://integrations.expensify.com/Integration-Server/ExpensifyIntegrations' \
-d 'requestJobDescription={
    "type":"file",
    "credentials":{
        "partnerUserID":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "partnerUserSecret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "onReceive":{
        "immediateResponse":["returnRandomFileName"]
    },
    "inputSettings":{
        "type":"combinedReportData",
        "filters":{
            "reportIDList":"1234567,2233445"
        }
    },
    "outputSettings":{
        "fileExtension":"csv"
    }
}'
--data-urlencode 'template@expensify_template.ftl'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just remove the trailing `\`'s and replace the newlines with spaces, and it should be cmd/.bat compatible.

```
curl -X POST 'https://integrations.expensify.com/Integration-Server/ExpensifyIntegrations' -d 'requestJobDescription={     "type":"file",     "credentials":{         "partnerUserID":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",         "partnerUserSecret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"     },     "onReceive":{         "immediateResponse":["returnRandomFileName"]     },     "inputSettings":{         "type":"combinedReportData",         "filters":{             "reportIDList":"1234567,2233445"         }     },     "outputSettings":{         "fileExtension":"csv"     } }' --data-urlencode 'template@expensify_template.ftl'
```

uhm, if your json happens to contain any instance of `'` however (but the example you provided here does not), you may need to prepend `%` to them (which acts as an escape character in cmd/.bat), and if the json data happens to include a newline, that newline should be json-escaped with `\n` instead of having the literal newline in the json data (i believe json accepts both newlines and \n in place of newlines, but that's asking for trouble with cmd)

Comment: I took out all the cr/lf's and the script now executes.  It returns errors, but that is for another post.  Looking to see if I can solve the errors myself.